# jquery and bootstrap error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am trying to build a UI using thymeleaf and i get the following error in the console

[image]

below is the code for my html.

[image]

can someone please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added jQuery-ui but it requires jQuery. Same for Bootstrap.js, it requires jQuery. Also, you're adding a number of libraries and stylesheets twice. For example, if you have bootstrap.min.js, you don't need bootstrap.js, because the former is a minified version of the later.

Comment: thanks i did that change and now I dont see any errors but my UI does not pick the css. can u let me know what i am missing ?

Comment: It is possible that the location of the file is incorrect. In your Internet Browser open Inspection Tool and click on Network tag. Can you see any errors?

Answer (score 2):

As the error says: you need to include [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library. You've provided [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com), which is the quite different library.

Answer (score 1):

To working with Bootstrap Js, There choice is Jquery. Without Jquery Bootstrap js will not work correctly.

So, first Add `jquery.min.js` and then try to insert `bootstrap.min.js`. Like,

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And then hope all errors will gone.